# Can't map <C-J> in Vim

Tags: mapping, vim

I have the following two mappings in my vimrc file

```
  nnoremap <C-j> :tabp<CR>
  nnoremap <C-k> :tabn<CR>
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> works, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> lands me in insert mode for some reason. If I issue the command `:nnoremap <C-j> :tabp<CR>` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> works correctly.

If I issue the command `:map` or `:verbose map` I see the mapping for `<C-k>` but nothing for `<C-j>`. Why is this happening?

Comment: You might have a plugin that `unmap`s or `nunmap`s `<c-j>` (`:helpgrep monastery` tells you about nunmap).

Comment: Maybe the mapping is being overwritten by some plugin. You can check that moving the statements to the bottom of your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: @jcollado I tried moving it to the bottom but that did not work.

Comment: @Benoit `:helpgrep monastery` does not provide any more information than can be gathered from looking at the commands `unmap` or `nunmap`. If it is unmapping `<C-j>`, is entering insert mode the default role?

Comment: standard behaviour of CTRL-J is the same as `down`, `return` or `ctrl-n` in normal mode: `[count] lines downward linewise movement.` Is that in a terminal? Can you post the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: @Benoit I figured it out, please see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plugin, [imaps.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=244) was interfering with the  command, most likely unmaping it (thanks to Benoit for pointing it out). If this happens to anyone else, just delete the plugin.